# Implementing a "take N" transform stream in Node

Tags: node.js, stream

I have a readable stream X, and a writable stream Z. I have no control over how many bytes of data stream X will produce. I want to stream no more than exactly N bytes of data from X to Z. I think a new transform stream Y, which will pass along all data it receives until the amount of data it's received exceeds its limit, could be a nice, clean solution. How do I implement such a stream?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the stream api from node.

Note that an endless reader would trigger some error as shows in the code below:

```js
const { Readable, Writable, Transform } = require('stream')

const source = new Readable({
  objectMode: true,
  read () {
    // endless writer
    this.push({ time: new Date() })
  }
})

let items = 0
const transformation = new Transform({
  objectMode: true,
  transform  (data, encoding, done) {
    if (items > 100) {
      done(null)
      this.end() // we must stop this stream
    } else {
      done(null, { ...data, index: items++ })
    }
  }
})

const destination = new Writable({
  objectMode: true,
  write (data, encoding, done) {
    console.log({ data })
    done()
  }
})

source
  .pipe(transformation)
  .on('error', () => { console.log('Error: it will be emitted because the READER will "write" in the transform stream but we closed it') })
  .pipe(destination)
  .on('finish', () => { console.log('All writes are now complete.') })
```